# How to pass method with arguments to thread to execution?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, stdthread

I have a method

```
void RobocopyCopy::monitoring_thread_method(std::string path_to_monior)
{
    while (!m_bMonitorThreadShouldExit)
    {
        printf("HERE WE ARE!!!! Path is :: %s\n", path_to_monior.c_str());
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}
```

I need to start it in the background, so I create a thread and would like to pass this method as an argument

```
void RobocopyCopy::start_monitoring_thread(std::string path_to_monior)
{
    m_bMonitorThreadShouldExit = false;
    m_pMonitoringThread = std::unique_ptr<std::thread>(new std::thread(&RobocopyCopy::monitoring_thread_method, path_to_monior, this));
}
```

I am getting such an error

```
>RobocopyCopy.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(238): error C2672: 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(246): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Execute<0,1,2>(std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *> &,std::integer_sequence<_Ty,0,1,2>)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *>>>,
1>            _Ty=size_t
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(245): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Execute<0,1,2>(std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *> &,std::integer_sequence<_Ty,0,1,2>)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *>>>,
1>            _Ty=size_t
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(242): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *) noexcept'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *>>>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(230): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *) noexcept' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *>>>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(257): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_LaunchPad<_Target>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *>>>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thread(49): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Launch<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *>,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>(_Thrd_t *,_Target &&)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *>,
1>            _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,RobocopyCopy *>>>
1>        ]
1>c:\tetavi_main2\tv_apps\tv_world2\tv_logic_cpp\robocopycopy.cpp(73): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::thread::thread<void(__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string),std::string&,RobocopyCopy*,void>(_Fn &&,std::string &,RobocopyCopy *&&)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Fn=void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string)
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(238): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept(<expr>)'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(238): note: With the following template arguments:
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(238): note: '_Callable=void (__cdecl RobocopyCopy::* )(std::string)'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(238): note: '_Types={std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>, RobocopyCopy *}'
1>Done building project "TV_Logic_CPP.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You pass 2 arguments to your `monitoring_thread_method` function, but it accepts only 1. Check this call `new std::thread(&RobocopyCopy::monitoring_thread_method, path_to_monior, this)`

Comment: Assuming `monitoring_thread_method` is a non-static member of `RobocopyCopy` you need `std::thread(&RobocopyCopy::monitoring_thread_method, this, path_to_monior)` -- note the order of the last two parameters.  There should be a suitable dupe for this somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 m_pMonitoringThread = std::make_unique<std::thread>(&RobocopyCopy::monitoring_thread_method, this, path_to_monior);
```